# Windows device name

Tags: winapi, windows-7, bluetooth, createfile

I'm trying to get a device name for a USB Bluetooth transceiver to use with CreateFile, but I don't know the file path. I've tried the USB file path but always return SHARING_VIOLATION.

In order to understand if that's the correct device path, how can I get Windows registered device names? Is there a standard device path for a Bluetooth transceiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward is likely [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to find the exact device name.

And I'm not aware of a standard name for the BT transceiver.

Comment: Is that the column where appears COM1 and G:/C: ?? If it is then my bluetooth adapter doesn't create any device.

Comment: @rnunes: nope. Strictly speaking those names are symlinks (in the object manager namespace) to the devices. Win32 only sees devices inside the `\??` (alias `\DosDevices`) object directory by default, which is why the Win32 names for devices get symlinked into this object directory in order for the Win32 subsystem to see them. The Device names should usually start with `\Device\`, although there can be exceptions ... it's a convention, though.

Comment: I've already did it, but unfortunately I don't think that my usb bluetooth adapter uses Windows Bluetooth Driver Stack (Bluesoleil stack). I've solved that problem using WinObj, tomorrow I'll post the solution